# Change component icons in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

How can I replace the icons used in Vaadin Flow components (calendar, upload etc) with my own icons? Is that even possible? I didn't see anything in component's API and it looks like the icons are font icons instead of the usual iron-icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the component icons are implemented using font icons. The main reason was that they should be customizable with a theme (CSS), which seemed impossible using iron-icon. Eventually we want to transition to using SVGs for the component icons as well.

So, to customize the component icons, you need to write a component style sheet, where you change the icon. You can either create your own icon font, or use a CSS background image. The latter option has the downside of not being able to change color easily, without swapping the whole image.

As an example, here’s what you’d write for the vaadin-date-picker component (assuming that’s what you meant by “calendar”).

```css
[part="toggle-button"]::before {
  content: ""; /* Remove the existing font based icon */
  background-image: url(...); /* data uri */
}
```

Use a base64 encoded data uri, so that you don’t have to worry about using relative or absolute paths for the image.

To use that style sheet in your Flow-based app, place CSS file in the `frontend` folder in your app, and add the following:

```java
@CssImport(value = "my-styles.css", themeFor="vaadin-date-picker")
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation. I will try the background image approach. And yes, you are right, I meant "date picker".